CodeBlock Vs Microsoft Visual Studio Different results compiling the same code
As a beginner in C++, I experimented with two different IDEs, running identical code. While Code Blocks compiled the code smoothly, Microsoft Visual Studio encountered an error. In both cases, I included the same header files. Can someone explain why I got two different results on the same code?
Microsoft Error: Error (active) E0289 no instance of constructor "TokenPos::TokenPos" matches the argument list xm C:\Users\barto\OneDrive\Desktop\Test\Markup.cpp 4618
Code Below:
#include <iostream>
#include "Markup.h"

int main() {
    CMarkup xml;
    // Create a root element
    xml.AddElem("Root");
    // Add some child elements
    xml.IntoElem(); // Go into the "Root" element
    xml.AddElem("Child1", "Value1");
    xml.AddElem("Child2", "Value2");
    xml.OutOfElem(); // Go back to the parent element
    // Save the XML to a file
    if (xml.Save("example.xml")) {
        std::cout << "XML document saved successfully." << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "Failed to save XML document." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    // Load the XML from the file
    if (xml.Load("example.xml")) {
        // Iterate over child elements and print their names and values
        xml.ResetPos(); // Reset the position to the beginning
        while (xml.FindElem()) {
            std::cout << "Element: " << xml.GetTagName() << ", Value: " << xml.GetData() << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "Failed to load XML document." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

I run both IDE's. CodeBlock complies without any trouble. On the other hand Microsoft Viusal Studions returns Error

Please take some time to format your code correctly.

your code doesn't contain TokenPos ... so maybe you forgot to add the rest of the code to visual studio ?

I'm pretty sure the code fragment shown doesn't even show the error. The Markup.h might have some compiler checks that go bad on some platforms, or there might be different compiler settings that cause things to change in some way. We don't have the Markup.h|cpp files, obviously, so there's no way to tell.

I used the same Markup.h file for both IDE's.

Are you using the same compiler on both?

Please show a [mre]

Check working folder and see if there are any dll in the folder.
